# How can we acheive Login/Logout/Registration Functionality in Tridion based website?

Tags: 2011, 2013

How can we achieve Login/Logout/Registration Functionality in a Tridion based website ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How would you do it in a *non-Tridion* based website?

Tridion does not provide user login/logout functionality, so you can choose whatever method best fits your requirements, technology and expertise.

The Audience Manager module will allow you to store and retrieve contacts, which you could leverage as a user database for your functionality, see the documentation link, "[Contact Subscription](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-800491A2-B402-4E2B-8C79-0FAF3EBA8593)" for more information.

If you use modules such as Audience Manager, Profiling and Personalisation, SmartTarget etc. then you can synchronise your users' information and preferences with Tridion in order to implicitly and explicitly target/personalise your content and get the most from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David . Can we store the website end user user information in Tridion provided User Rights and Groups Section                      Or ideally this section should be reserved for Access to the on Tridion CME Users only And instead we should use the Basic .NET Membership for managing the Website end user information ?   Also, if we create a login page in Tridion CME, how can we handle the business logic for checking the user login on the login button click?

Comment: You cannot use the Tridion provided security and authorisation system for this, as it is for Content **Management** only, not Content **Delivery**. Tridion decouples management and delivery, meaning that they are not available at the end-point from where your web site is delivered. You should not create a login page in the CME for the same reason.

Comment: There is a nice blogpost about using the Audience Manager as a Membership provider in .NET here: http://erichuiza.blogspot.nl/2013/10/integrating-asp-net-security-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the registration/login/logout in few ways.
depends on how and where you want to maintain the users (user profiles in tridion are  stored in TRUSTEES table in the tridion schema/DB)
1st approach, If you want to use an external authentication system, 1st would be to hook up the IIS with a policy server (ex: siteminder). and synchronize the users in tridion to that external system
You can provide the registration form that would post the user details to tridion schema and create the user profile ther and have the users enabled by CMS admin by putting a process around it. Once user is enabled in tridion, that gets synchronized with the external system and the policy server will handle it. Lot more happens with the above setup.

2nd approach To simplify it, you can just have the CMS admin enable the registered user and the login button can be posted to a logic that checks if the user id is active in tridion and redirect to tridion dashboard page. If user is still not enabled, he can be routed to a sorry page.